# UISplitViewController as a segue target

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIViewController. A button on the UIView should bring the user to a UISplitViewController. I'm using a segue for that, setup using the storyboard UI.

While some answers here seem to suggest this might not work (UISplitViewController has to be the root - or does this  mean something different?), this does indeed work. Except - The SplitViewController on iPhone always starts with its *DetailView*, not with the MasterView.

What can be done about that?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot use splitViewControllers with iPhones, so you will have to use separate code to handle the iPhone version of your app(unless they have released something recently enabling this). 
You could say

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
  // Show your master view
} else {
  // Present normally
}
```